# How to use the global variables in django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, global-variables

I want to use word (english) dictionary in my Django application. However Django does not recommend using Global variables because of its threading model. This dictionary does not have thread-safety issues, I want to load the dictionary at the beginning and after it is constant (will be reading that from different Django views).

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: use for store regular python file, if you will be only read it, there is no place for race conditions, don`t worry

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dictionary in your `static` directory and put the path in your `settings.py` file. Then when you try to use it, you load the dictionary in your `views.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Your can chose for it constants.py file created by yourself. For example,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
SUMMER_MONTHS = {'june': 'June', 'july': 'July', 'august': 'August'}
```

And use it like this

```
import constants as CONSTS
print CONSTS.SUMMER_MONTHS
```

Comment: Thank you. i will give a try.